# Can a Raspberry Pi handle 2 external HDDs and a keyboard/mouse?

Tags: pi-3

I just got the CanaKit Raspberry Pi 3 starter kit, and I was wondering if it can handle all of the following via its USB ports:

1. **[BlackArmor WS 110 2TB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BH4R9U)**
2. **[Seagate FreeAgent Desk 1 TB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FWEETK)**
3. (**Wireless**) **Keyboard and mouse** (both via USB dongles)

The power supply that comes with the kit is **2.5A**.

I plan to use it as a **media server** (e.g. via ***plex***).

Would the above be fine?

Comment: I wouldn't try it, just get a powered USB hub to be safe.

Comment: @PatrickCook Does it make a difference that both HDDs have external power supplies and that the RPi3 power supply is 2.5A? If not, can you recommend a good hub?

Comment: If the HDDs have their own power supply, then they are drawing little to no power from the Pi, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those HDDs have external power supplies, so they would work just fine.

I wouldn't recommend you use a HDD that uses only power from the Raspberry Pi for two reasons:

1. You would need a very powerful power adapter, and considering that RPI 3 needs over 1.34 A ([here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerHub)) any normal power adapter will fail.
2. You are relying on the power from the RPi - for a device which really needs a reliable PSU, which is not the case with RPi.

Wireless keyboard+mouse are using very little power compared to a non-powered HDD.

Comment: So I take it the above setup should run fine without any (power) issues, right? 
Thanks!

Comment: True. Just hope they provide a good power supply :)

Answer (score 1):

There exists expansion boards for the Raspberry Pi that gives you a SATA interface. This will be a lot faster than communicating with a HDD through USB. It will still need a separate power supply though.

Take a look here for an example. Available at eBay if I recall correctly:

http://www.suptronics.com/xseries/x300.html